# Adding my own functions to Vis.js network

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vis.js

I'm working towards my vis graph doing double duty in displaying my application's database and also manipulating it.  I'm stuck on adding new instances of objects, and a desired outcome --- I only need one! --- could take one of several forms I can think of:

1) A popup menu solution.  I've been experimenting with tooltip popups and think I could make these work, but tooltips don't display in vis ("you found me" does not pop-up for the node described below).  One of StackOverflow's (SO) posts noted that tooltips are set to hidden by default in the vis .css.  I tried creating my own copy of the .css on my server so I could change this default, but I'm having trouble getting my page to work properly with my version.  Putting aside configuring the custom .css properly for the moment, can't I enable tooltip visibility programatically?  I know how to alter an element's attribute through jQuery, but don't know which element to reference or if the .css angle adds complications beyond my experience.

```
           nodeSet.push({id:"47", 
                         label:"some object type", 
                         font:{color: 'purple'},
                         title:"<span id='nodeManipulation'>you found me</span>",
                         url:"/BackToTech/server?function=viewGraph&NodeID=47"});
```

2) Commandeering the add button in the editing pane.  I did this successfully with the delete button, but the add button does some pre- behaviors before it gets to the user-provided function that is interfering.  The sequence I want is:

- Select an object type
- Click the Add button
- Post redirect browser to the new instance creation portal for selected object type

What actually happens is:

- Select an object type
- Click the Add button
- The network tells me to click off into empty space (deselect) where I want my new node to go
- The code I supply can't tell what object type to make an instance of

  ```
  addNode: function(nodeData,callback) {
                          var selected = network.getSelectedNodes();
                          if (selected.length > 1) { 
                              alert("narrow your selection down to one type.");
                              return;
                          } else if (selected.length < 1) {
                              alert("select a type first.");
                              return;
                          } else {
                              var node = nodes.get(selected[0]);
                                  createInstance(node);
                          }
                        //nodeData.label = 'hello world';
                        //callback(nodeData);
                      }
  ```

3) Adding my own buttons to the editing bar. This will be tomorrow's attempt.  I've saved it for last since there's a lot about vis's .js and .css , while I appreciate them, that is like a black box to me. I'm anticipating my versions to be unaesthetic and/or have unforeseen poor interactions mingling with the native buttons. I'll add more specific descriptions of these if I become confounded, but for the moment any advice on what to look out for or similar example from my more experienced brethren would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

While I still hope to have tooltips someday, I got #3 to work.  Some hidden post-processing was resetting the edit bar and wiping out my button adds within the 'selectNode' handler, despite having all of the manipulation functions set to false.  The add delay was my work-around for that.  Next I'll add a navigate button, and remove all of them on the unselect event.

```
    network.on("selectNode", function (params) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                var manipulationBar = $(".vis-manipulation");
                $("<div>")
                    .attr("class", "vis-button")
                    .attr("id", "myAdd")
                    .attr('onclick', "addNode()")
                    .attr('style', 'display: block; white-space:nowrap;align-items: center')
                    .appendTo(manipulationBar);
                $('<img>')
                    .attr('src', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/img/network/addNodeIcon.png")
                    .attr('height',"20")
                    .attr('style', "vertical-align: baseline")
                    .appendTo($("#myAdd"));
                $("<span>")
                    .attr("class", "vis-label")
                    .attr("style", "text-align: center; font-size:20px")
                    .text("Add New")
                    .appendTo($("#myAdd"));

                $("<div>")
                    .attr("class", "vis-separator-line")
                    .appendTo(manipulationBar);

                $("<div>")
                    .attr("class", "vis-button")
                    .attr("id", "myDelete")
                    .attr('style', 'display: block; white-space:nowrap;align-items: center')
                    .attr('onclick', "deleteNode()")
                    .appendTo(manipulationBar);
                $('<img>')
                    .attr('src', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.19.1/img/network/deleteIcon.png")
                    .attr('height',"20")
                .appendTo($("#myDelete"));
                $("<span>")
                    .attr("class", "vis-label")
                    .attr("style", "text-align: center; font-size:20px")
                    .text("Delete")
                    .appendTo($("#myDelete"));
            }, 100);
        });
```